# Session control

Tags: php, html, session

Sometimes the sessions arent working and I just need some advice and help here.

**Login code:**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$query = "SELECT wachtwoord, naam, status, email FROM leden WHERE email = '$username' AND wachtwoord = '$password' LIMIT 1";
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$username);
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $resusername = $row['naam'];
    $respassword = $row['wachtwoord'];
    $resemail = $row['email'];
    $resstatus = $row['status'];

}
    $teller = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($teller == 1) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['email'] = $resemail;
        $_SESSION['naam'] = $resusername;
        $_SESSION['status'] = $resstatus;
        $_SESSION['start_time'] = time();
        echo "<div class=\"confirmation-box round\">Je bent nu ingelogd je word doorgestuurd in 3 seconden.</div>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3;URL=**********/home_.php\" />";
        }else{
        echo "<div class=\"error-box round\">E-mail of wachtwoord komt niet overeen.</div>"; } }
?>
```

**Check if session exists(open):**

```
if (empty($_SESSION['naam'])){
die("Log eerst in voordat u deze pagina bezoekt.");
}
```

**On everypage:**

```
ob_start();
session_start();
```

What am I doing wrong that the system has failures sometimes? advice is welcome my english isnt that perfect so please if u point me in a direction make it clear what u mean so I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind switched to cookies sessions are useless.